# convert ANSI C's asctime() format using std::get_time

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime

I want to convert string in ANSI C' format to `std::tm` object.

Example

> Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994       ; ANSI C's asctime() format

More info here [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html).

---

## My code:

```
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
bool parseAscTimeDate(std::tm& tm, const std::string& str) {
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    //ss.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF8")); //try timezone?
    ss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
    return !ss.fail();
}
```

So why this fail?

```
   /* ANSI C's asctime format */
   std::tm tm;
   if (parseAscTimeDate(tm, "Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994"))
       std::cout << "Ok!" << std::endl;
   else
       std::cout << "Wrong!" << std::endl;
```

---

### additional info

1. I can't use `strptime` because there is a bug in musl libc.
2. I have tried to set some timezone but:

> It need not set tzname, timezone, and daylight.

From [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/asctime)

3. [std::get_time example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/mani/get_time) that also fails?

Comment: As a workaround, you could use Howard Hinnant's free, open source, datetime library:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date which will work with gcc as demonstrated here:  https://wandbox.org/permlink/NdM8PnHG9VgOMZJd

Answer (score 5):

It looks like `%d` format requires two digits for the day of the month, contrary to description on [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time):

> **d**: parses the day of the month as a decimal number (range [01,31]), **leading zeroes permitted but not required**.

It is a reported bug in GNU C++ standard library: [set::get_time() requires leading 0s for %H and friends](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71556).

Comment: He's right [see it at ideone](https://ideone.com/Fvryfa) with `06` instead of `6` it is working.

Comment: *Say it to ANSI C format*. Any workaround? So I can't use `strptime` and now `std::get_time`.  Is any portable solutions for that?

Comment: It's fail with ** RFC-1123 ** (using musl instead of glibc). And `std::get_time` fail with ** ANSI C's asctime format **.

Comment: @S.R Hmm..., I am not familiar with error code _RFC-1123 / (using musl instead of glibc)_. I would try repoducing the problem, and may be try https://github.com/esmil/musl/blob/master/src/time/strptime.c.

Comment: It's not an error code. It's data format. You have more info here. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html . (3.3.1)